How to fix virtualbox's copy and paste to guest-machine?
I have the reverse problem of this question:
How to fix virtualbox's copy and paste to host-machine?
Sometimes, I am able to copy-paste from guest to host (both Ubuntu), but not from host to guest, even though Shared Clipboard is set to bidirectional. For example, yesterday both directions were working fine, and I paused the VM for the night. Today I resumed work on the VM, and host to guest copy paste no longer works.

Have you looked at support for the Virtual Box?

@DavidDE no, I have not contacted VirtualBox support

I guess I was not clear I suggest that you do.
